# Ruby prompt environment not connecting to gvim text editor

Tags: ruby, vim

I am a Rails newbie and in following a video tutorial got to a point where I have to open Ruby command prompt environment.

The problem is I want to use gvim as as my text editor, but I can't seem to get it to work. It gives an error message that reads

```
gvim is not a recognizable internal or external command, operable programme or batch file
```

Answer (score 1):

gvim may not be installed in your system. gvim is a popular open-source text editor. 
You didn't mention which operating system you are using. 
You can install gvim from http://www.vim.org/download.php

If you are on Linux, you can work on `vim` instead of gvim to check if you are doing the things properly.
Good luck.

Comment: Thanks,I am currently using running windows 7 on my system, i have managed to get it to work but having serious compatibility issues, any ideas on a good text editor?

Comment: Compatibility issues? As in working around with gvim? In that case, you can try using Notepad++ as text editor.

Comment: Though, I'll seriously recommend you to learn some basic vim. It's simple and awesome. [link](http://www.openvim.com/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

What OS do you use?

i think you use win or mac. on linux you may use vim out of the box. if it's mac or win you need to install vim or gvim from [vim official site](http://www.vim.org/download.php).

after you need to customize you vim to work fine with ruby.
[for example](http://biodegradablegeek.com/2007/12/using-vim-as-a-complete-ruby-on-rails-ide/)

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

When you install gvim in Windows, you have to click a checkbox to install command-line binaries. Try reinstalling gvim and clicking that checkbox.